# Is it true the derivative of the length of a Lipschitz path equals its speed? (when they exist)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, curves, lipschitz-functions

$\newcommand{\ga}{\gamma}$
$\newcommand{\e}{\epsilon}$
I have the following situation:

$(X,d)$ is a metric space. $\gamma:[0,1] \to X$ is a **Lipschitz path**. The *speed* of $\gamma$ is defined as $$ \nu_{\ga}(s):=\lim_{\e \to 0} \frac{d\left( \ga(s),\ga(s+\e) \right)}{|\e|},
$$ if the limit exists.

Define $g(t)=L(\ga|_{[0,t]})$, and assume $g'(t_0),\nu_{\ga}(t_0)$ exist for a specific $t_0 \in [0,1]$.
Is it true that $g'(t_0)=\nu_{\ga}(t_0)$?

**Note:**

It is a known theorem, that for any **Lipschitz path** $\ga$, the speed $\nu_{\ga}(t)$ exists for almost all $t$, and $L(\ga)=\int \nu_{\ga}(t) dt$ (See "A course in metric geometry" by Burago,Burago and Ivanov, theorem 2.7.6).

In fact, the proof actually shows that for almost all $t$, $g'(t),\nu_{\ga}(t)$ exist and are equal. I am asking about their equality **at a single point** (assuming existence).

**Partial Results:**

$$g'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}L(\ga|_{[0,t]})=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0+} \frac{L(\ga|_{[0,t+\Delta t]})-L(\ga|_{[0,t]})}{\Delta t}=\lim_{\Delta t \to 0+} \frac{L(\ga|_{[t,t+\Delta t]})}{\Delta t} $$

$$ \ge  \lim_{\Delta t \to 0+} \frac{d\left( \ga(t),\ga(t+\Delta t) \right)}{\Delta t} = \nu_{\ga}(t)$$

So, we established $g'(t) \ge \nu_{\ga}(t) $.

The question about the other direction still remains.

In the special case, where $X$ is a length space, and $\gamma$ is a geodesic (i.e locally a shortest path), we have that $d\left( \ga(t),\ga(t+\Delta t) \right)=L(\ga|_{[t,t+\Delta t]})$ (for small enough $\Delta t$), so the equality obviously holds.

Perhaps it will be easier to prove this for length spaces, but without the assumption that $\ga$ is a geodesic, I do not see how it helps.

Comment: I presume I am missing someting, but is this not an immediate consequence of $g(t) = \int_0^t \nu_\gamma(\tau) d \tau$?

Comment: @copper.hat No, it isn't, since $\nu_{\gamma}(\tau)$ is not necessarily a continuous function of $\tau$ (it does not even have to be defined for all $\tau$).

Comment: @AsafShachar: I realise that, but it is integrable so you have $g'(t) = \nu_\gamma(t)$ at any Lebesgue point (which means ae. here).

Comment: @copper.hat I am not sure. I do believe this is true, but I have no rigorous justification yet. I do not see how the concept of Lebesgue point helps here (as far as I can see, the assertion does not follow from any differentiation theorem I know of).

Comment: @AsafShachar: It is true, see, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem. The integral (as in $\int_0^t$) of any $L^1$ function is ae. differentiable and the derivative of the integral is the integrand.

Comment: @copper.hat  you are right that there is an equality *a.e*. However, I am asking something a bit different: Take a specific point $x$, and assume that the derivative (of the integral) and the integrand both exist at $x$. Are they equal (at $x$)? I do not think this is implied by Lebesgue's theorem.

Comment: @AsafShachar: Sorry, I need to read more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have the strict inequality $\nu_{\gamma}(t_0) < g'(t_0)$.

Let $(X,d)$ be the Euclidean plane, and let $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the path with

$$\gamma(n^{-1}) = \bigl(n^{-1}, (-1)^n\cdot n^{-2}\bigr)$$

for $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, linearly interpolating between $\gamma(n^{-1})$ and $\gamma\bigl((n+1)^{-1}\bigr)$, and by continuity $\gamma(0) = (0,0)$. One easily verifies that $\gamma$ is a Lipschitz path with Lipschitz constant $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{29}$.

Further, for $0 < t \leqslant 1$, we have $t \leqslant d(\gamma(t),\gamma(0)) \leqslant t\sqrt{1 + t^2}$, so $\nu_{\gamma}(0)$ exists, and $\nu_{\gamma}(0) = 1$.

For $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$, we have

$$\frac{\sqrt{5}}{(n+1)^2} < L(\gamma\lvert_{[(n+1)^{-1}, n^{-1}]}) = \sqrt{n^{-2}(n+1)^{-2} + \bigl(n^{-2} + (n+1)^{-2}\bigr)^2} < \frac{\sqrt{5}}{n^2},$$

and hence for $t \in \bigl((k+1)^{-1}, k^{-1}\bigr]$

$$\frac{\sqrt{5}}{k+2} < \sum_{n = k+1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{5}}{(n+1)^2} < L(\gamma\lvert_{[0,t]}) < \sum_{n = k}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{5}}{n^2} < \frac{\sqrt{5}}{k-1},$$

whence

$$\sqrt{5}\frac{k}{k+2} < \frac{g(t)}{t} < \sqrt{5}\frac{k+1}{k-1},$$

which shows $g'(0) = \sqrt{5} > \nu_{\gamma}(0)$.

Comment: Thanks! This is very interesting. Can you say something about how you bound (from above and below) the partial sums of the series $\sum_{n = k}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$? I do not see why this holds.

Comment: I use $$\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{1}{n(n+1)} < \frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{(n-1)n} = \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}.$$ The upper and lower bounds telescope nicely.

Comment: By the way, it seems to me your path $\gamma$ is even differentiable at $t=0$ (and the derivative is $(1,0)$). Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.